# Like box showing duplicate posts

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-likebox

I've set up a like box for my band's website using this page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

The Facebook page for my band is http://www.facebook.com/zeligmusic

When I add the URL into the Like Box plugin page, I am getting the first two posts from the Facebook page repeated. The first post is from earlier today, the next is from 9th Feb. These two posts are being duplicated in the stream. Posts from before that, the most recent being from 31st December, are fine and are only being displayed once.

Can anyone shed any light on why this is happening? And if there is anything I can do to fix it?

Many thanks,
Will

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug:  http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/220672548026208

You should go there and mark it as reproducible and also subscribe to it so you can watch for updates.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.
That sounds like the same issue I'm having.
How do I mark it as reproducable and subscribe? There is nothing on that page you linked to to let me do that? Or do I have to create a new bug?

Comment: The [+ subscribe] button is in the upper right. Click where it says [1 person] can reproduce this issue to tell them about your experience with it.

Comment: Hi,
I don't mean to sound/appear daft, but I'm not getting a [+ subscribe] anywhere on the page. Also, when I click on the [1 person] link I just get a list of that one person with the option to add them as a friend.
Could this be a "permissions" issue? I've added a screenshot of how I'm seeing the page, just in case I'm missing something painfully obvious.
http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7043/6872658063_f4065cc62c_b.jpg

Comment: I have also noticed that when I am logged in to Facebook as the page admin for which I have created the Like Box, I can't see the iframe that I have embedded on my website.
The page is here - http://www.zeligmusic.co.uk/2012/nunc.html
If I am logged out of Facebook, or logged in as me (William Machin), I can see the Like Box, albeit with duplicate posts. If, however, I'm using Facebook "as a page", then the area of the webpage with the Like Box is totally blank.
Is this a related/known issue, or should I start a new post about this problem?